# AWS Cloud-formation intrinsic function inside jinja

Tags: amazon-web-services, jinja2, aws-cloudformation

I have a jinja macro for AWS cloud-formation where I am trying to evaluate a jinja expression which also has an intrinsic cloud-formation function, like:

```
{{ ${Ref: MyParam}.capitalize() }}
```

Basically I want to access the MyParam parameter and then capitalize the first letter, but jinja would not evaluate the param. It gives:

> jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError

How can I achieve to do this?

Answer (score 0):

[Jinja](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/) is a templating language for Python. That means you can use it in you CloudFormation configuration yaml/json files in order to have some basic logic, especially useful for repetitive components.

There is a restriction, that you cannot have AWS intrinsic functions evaluated in Jinja. In other words, Jinja executes first, then whatever Jinja builds is passed as a plain yml/json to CloudFormation.

In your example: `{{ ${Ref: MyParam}.capitalize() }}`

`${Ref: MyParam}` doesn't mean anything to Jinja, i.e. you don't have the parameter value that you want it capitalized. First Jinja template is built, then at deploy time CloudFormation knows what *MyParam* is, so it fetches its value from the parameters and replaces the placeholder in the configuration.